# Remove duplicates from main page

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, homepage

Confirmed duplicates are no good to us once they have been linked to the appropriate original question.
Is it possible to remove those posts from the main feed once they have been confirmed as duplicates? I mean there are so many of them.

> [image: main page with the "duplicate" label circled]

Comment: @Lance or [just one space](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2544/how-many-spaces-should-come-after-a-period-full-stop).

Comment: @AaronBertrand, not sure if you were joking or not, I was referring to markdown and how if you put two spaces at the end of a line and then hit return, it will give you a line break.

Comment: @Lance no I thought you meant they should add two spaces at the end of a sentence (I did not view your revision or know that they literally typed `<br>`).

Answer (score 2):

People don't use that view just to find questions to answer.  They also use it to, for example, look at recently closed questions (including those closed as a duplicate) to see if the actions taken were correct (i.e. that the question is indeed a duplicate).

You can of course always use other sources, such as the "unanswered" tab or search to look for questions without having duplicates shown to you.

Comment: To me seeing dupes in the main feed is as bad as seing `-x questions` that are hidden. I think duplicates should be hidden too. But anyway thats my opinion

Comment: @insertcleverxmasname I don't think -x questions should be hidden; I find it unfortunate that they are.  It makes getting the views to close/delete them harder on main sites, and on meta they may simply be discussions worth participating in despite the score.

Comment: I agree that the fact they should be hidden or not is up to discuss. But I like consistency and to it seems to me that the duplicates should be hidden with the other or none should be hidden at all.

Comment: I thought there was a way to set whether "hidden" posts were actually hidden or just dimmed.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I've never heard of it.  I know the score at which they're hidden is configurable per site, i.e. meta has a much lower limit than main sites.  If there is such a setting, I'd love to know about it.

Comment: I might be remembering something else (and of course I can't find it now). It might be about hiding or dimming ignored tags?

Comment: @AaronBertrand That is a setting, yes.